# Passing int to BroadcastReceiver class using alarm manager

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager

i am trying to pass two integers through the alarmmanger but whenever i pass them the toast replies null . i can't understand where the problem is .

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);

        intent.putExtra("passedHour", cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        intent.putExtra("passedMin", cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

        PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                MainActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                alarmIntent);
```

This is the  onreceive in alaramreceiver class

```
Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm!! " + intent.getStringExtra("passedHour") + ":" + intent.getStringExtra("passedMin"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: `Calendar#get()` returns an `int`. You're trying to retrieve it from the `Intent` as a `String`. Use the `Intent#getIntExtra()` method instead.

Comment: Use `getIntExtra` instead of `getStringExtra` for getting both keys value from intent because `Calendar` `get` method return type is `int` instead of `String`

Comment: Yeah thnxs guys it worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cal.get()` method return int so intent is sending value as int
You need to use `intent.getIntExtra` method in order to get int
So in the onReceive use

```
Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm!! " + intent.getIntExtra("passedHour") + ":" + intent.getIntExtra("passedMin"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```